# Increasing the product cost with Quantity.( Added toa For-Loop

Tags: javascript, html

How to add a function inside a For Loop. I'm trying to add a feature to increase the cost with increase in product. But Unable to add this inside a For-loop.

Html

```
<div class="slider-vertical"></div>
<div id="purhcaseForm">
     <form id="purchase">

         <br> Please Select Quantity
         <input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='Total("qty",-1,"total",250);' value='-'/>
         <input type='button' name='add' onclick='Total("qty",1,"total",250);' value='+'/>
         <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' readonly=true value="0"/>
         <input type='text' name='total' id='total' value="0" />
      </form>
</div>
```

For-Loop

```
for ( var i=0; i<Boys.length; i++ ){

  Boys_Toys += '<div class="card"> <h2>'+Boys[i].name+'</h2> <img src='+Boys[i].image+' style="width:250px" border="3px"><p class="Cost">$ '+Boys[i].Cost+'</p> <p> <button> Add to cart </button> </p> <div class="slider-vertical">  <div id="purhcaseForm"> <form id="purchase"> <p> Please Select Quantity </p> <input type="button" name="subtract" onclick="Total(\'qty\',-1,\'total\',250);" value="-"/> <input type="button" name="add" onclick="Total(\'qty\',1,\'total\',250);" value="+"/> <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" readonly=true value="0"/> <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0" /> </div></form> </div> </div>';
}
```

Function

```
function Total(qty, ud, total, value, cart) {
  qty = document.getElementById("qty",);
  ud > 0 ? qty.value++ : qty.value--;
  qty.value = Math.max(qty.value, 0);
  document.getElementById("total",).value = qty.value * value;

}
```

Expected to increase each product cost with quantity.

```js
<script>
 


var Boys = [{name:"Rubix cube", Cost:250, image:"Pictures/3x3-Rubix-Cube.jpg"},
   {name:"Drone", Cost:5000, image:"Pictures/Rc.Drone.jpg"},
   {name:"Aeroplane", Cost:3000, image:"Pictures/Rc.Plane.jpg"},
   {name:"Cars", Cost:1500, image:"Pictures/Rc.Car.jpg"},
   {name:"Rc.Hellio", Cost:1000, image:"Pictures/Rc.Hellio.jpg"},
   {name:"Brown Teddy", Cost:800, image:"Pictures/Teddy.jpg"}];


//var products = [document.getElementById("purhcaseForm","purchase")];

//var Cost = [250, 50000, 3000, 1500, 1000, 800]; 

var Quantity = [document.getElementById("total","qty")];

var Boys_Toys=  "  ";

//var images = ["Pictures/3x3-Rubix-Cube.jpg","Pictures/Rc.Drone.jpg","Pictures/Rc.Plane.jpg","Pictures/Rc.Car.jpg","Pictures/Rc.Hellio.jpg" ,"Pictures/Teddy.jpg"];

for ( var i=0; i<Boys.length; i++ ){

  Boys_Toys += '<div class="card"> <h2>'+Boys[i].name+'</h2> <img src='+Boys[i].image+' style="width:250px" border="3px"><p class="Cost">$ '+Boys[i].Cost+'</p> <p> <button> Add to cart </button> </p> <div class="slider-vertical">  <div id="purhcaseForm"> <form id="purchase"> <p> Please Select Quantity </p> <input type="button" name="subtract" onclick="Total(\'qty\',-1,\'total\',250);" value="-"/> <input type="button" name="add" onclick="Total(\'qty\',1,\'total\',250);" value="+"/> <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" readonly=true value="0"/> <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0" /> </div></form> </div> </div>';
}


//for ( var i=0; i<Quantity.length;i++){

 //Quantity += '<div class="slider-vertical"><h2>'+Quantity[i].name+'</h2></div>';
//}

console.log(Boys_Toys);

document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML= Boys_Toys;




function Total(qty, ud, total, value, cart) {
  qty = document.getElementById("qty",);
  ud > 0 ? qty.value++ : qty.value--;
  qty.value = Math.max(qty.value, 0);
  document.getElementById("total",).value = qty.value * value;

}
  



</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>


<style>

.card {

width:300px;

height:500px;

float:left;

}


.product_image {

width: 49px;

height:150px;

border: 5px #000000 solid;

}


</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>


<title>Toy-World.</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#cbc8c8">



<div class="slider-vertical"></div>
<div id="purhcaseForm">
  <form id="purchase">
   
   <br> Please Select Quantity
   <input type='button' name='subtract' onclick='Total("qty",-1,"total",250);' value='-'/>
   <input type='button' name='add' onclick='Total("qty",1,"total",250);' value='+'/>
   <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' readonly=true value="0"/>
   <input type='text' name='total' id='total' value="0" />
      </form>
</div>

</body>


<h1 align="Center"> <u>Toy-World</u> </h1>

<div id="cart"></div>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

[Each product has a value already given trying to use this feature in a for loop to increase the cost with quantity.

Comment: What is the `<form id="purchase">` trying to accomplish? Add and substract what? I am asking because is not assigned to a product and has predefined values. Is it suposed to be the total of shoppings? If so it should be readonly I think. Else add or substract what from the prices? Other than that there are several things that needs to be fixed, but, in order to have an answer I think that should be clarified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to consider and make sure what you want to accomplish. My guess is that the first line should be total price, and than you want to have price and quantity for each product, then when the users push `Add to cart` button you want to push the items from that product to the total price.

In order to do that you first have to give different id's to your generated elements. In your code every `qty` input has `id='qty'` and every `price` input has `id='price'`. You should always avoid having more elements with same id. In order to fix that you can use the same i you use for indexing.

Then, when you call the `Total` function you don't really need the `qty` string or `total` string. You can just use them in the function. But what you need is the index to know witch element was added or substracted. You also don't use the card variable anywhere so if you don't need it, get rid of it.

After you need an addToCart function to actually update the total price. But in order to be able to modify the price you need to keep records for each product. So if the user selects 10 products, add them to cart, then remove (or add another) 4, then if he push the add to cart button again, you know from where, and how much you need to substract.

I did a working example. I hope I didn't misunderstood, but please try to be more clear in the future :)

```js
var Boys = [{name:"Rubix cube", Cost:250, image:"Pictures/3x3-Rubix-Cube.jpg"},
   {name:"Drone", Cost:5000, image:"Pictures/Rc.Drone.jpg"},
   {name:"Aeroplane", Cost:3000, image:"Pictures/Rc.Plane.jpg"},
   {name:"Cars", Cost:1500, image:"Pictures/Rc.Car.jpg"},
   {name:"Rc.Hellio", Cost:1000, image:"Pictures/Rc.Hellio.jpg"},
   {name:"Brown Teddy", Cost:800, image:"Pictures/Teddy.jpg"}];


//var products = [document.getElementById("purhcaseForm","purchase")];

//var Cost = [250, 50000, 3000, 1500, 1000, 800]; 

var Quantity = [document.getElementById("total","qty")];

var Boys_Toys=  "  ";

//var images = ["Pictures/3x3-Rubix-Cube.jpg","Pictures/Rc.Drone.jpg","Pictures/Rc.Plane.jpg","Pictures/Rc.Car.jpg","Pictures/Rc.Hellio.jpg" ,"Pictures/Teddy.jpg"];

for ( let i=0; i<Boys.length; i++ ){

  Boys_Toys += '<div class="card"> <h2>'+Boys[i].name+'</h2> <img src='+Boys[i].image+' style="width:250px" border="3px"><p class="Cost">$ '+Boys[i].Cost+'</p> <p> <button onclick="AddToCart('+i+');"> Add to cart </button> </p> <div class="slider-vertical">  <div id="purhcaseForm"> <form id="purchase"> <p> Please Select Quantity </p> <input type="button" name="subtract" onclick="Total(-1,'+Boys[i].Cost+','+i+');" value="-"/> <input type="button" name="add" onclick="Total(1,'+Boys[i].Cost+','+i+');" value="+"/> <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty'+i+'" readonly=true value="0"/> <input type="text" name="total" id="total'+i+'" value="0" /> </div></form> </div> </div>';
}



document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML= Boys_Toys;

let totalValues = [];


function Total(ud, value, index) {
  let qty = document.getElementById("qty" + index).value;
  ud > 0 ? qty++ : qty--;
  qty = Math.max(qty, 0);
  console.log(`total${index} && qty=${qty} && value=${value} && ud=${ud}`);
  document.getElementById("qty" + index).value = qty;
  document.getElementById("total"+index).value = qty * value;
}

function AddToCart(index) {
  totalValues[index] = Number(document.getElementById("total"+index).value);
  let totalPrice = 0;
  for(value of totalValues) {
    totalPrice +=value
  }
  document.getElementById("total-price").value = totalPrice;
}
```

```css
.card {

width:300px;

height:500px;

float:left;

}


.product_image {

width: 49px;

height:150px;

border: 5px #000000 solid;

}
```

```html
<div class="slider-vertical"></div>
<div id="purhcaseForm">
  <form id="purchase">
   
   <br> Total Price:
   <input type='text' readonly=true  name='total' id='total-price' value="0" />
      </form>
</div>

</body>


<h1 align="Center"> <u>Toy-World</u> </h1>

<div id="cart"></div>

</div>
```